# Group and search list-items alphabetically

Tags: jquery, sorting, search, grouping

I'm currently trying to create a bit of jQuery that looks through a unordened list, sorts the items based on their first letter and groups these items also based on the first letter of the 'organisation'.

I then need to find a way to show the items based on an array of letters (show A-F, G-K, etc etc).

At the moment I can sort the list alphabetically and add a classname to each list item based on the first character, but I'm stuck on groupîng and showing the correct letters.

I've made a jsfiddle to show what my progress is (http://jsfiddle.net/jbcarey/DdD8V/) - I also share the required design - http://nl.tinypic.com/r/63rcxl/8

I'm hoping someone can help me finish this 'plugin'?

here is the code I currently have

```
    //SORT LIST ALPHABETICALLY
var mylist = $('ul.elf_organisatie');
var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
     return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
})

//ADD CLASS TO LISTITEM
$.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { 
    mylist.append(itm); 
    $(this).addClass($(this).find('a').text().slice(0,1));
});

//GROUP LIST BY Letter

//Group Letter in "sets"

//Search and show specific set.
```

Comment: First of all, I’d suggest to add a class for the _group_ as well – `group_0-9`, `group_A-Z` or something similar; that way, you can easily “filter” your entries by group. And then, build a new list, that contains an item for every digit/letter – and into that, append a sub-list that the matching items get appended to.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DdD8V/2/ – still kinda _quick&dirty_ in some places – improving it let up to you :-) (F.e. you might want to disable selector links on top that refer empty groups, etc.)

Comment: CBroe, thanks a bunch, it's doing a whole lot more then it initially was and I can definatly try and refactor and improve the code!!

Comment: There seems to be a bug, where the letter Z doesn't get placed in the correct area? I'm looking for the error, but I suspect your better at it, perhaps you could check, please?

Comment: Oh yeah, the group index got only advanced by one when going out of the current group while looping over the items – simple fix, `if` replaced by a `while` loop: http://jsfiddle.net/DdD8V/3/

Comment: That's awesome and fixed it!! thanks a lot :-D